# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoId' not found in

Tags: php, mongodb

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoId' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\grup_prueba\mod_autor.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\grup_prueba\mod_autor.php on line 23

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu código como texto por favor

Comment: Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico. Revisa el centro de ayuda y documentate de como hacer una buena pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**`new MongoId()`** esta obsoleto, debería de ser:

```
new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId()
```